# Optaplanner newbie: nurse softconstraint for weekends

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm studying Optaplanner, and am doing some experiments with the Nursing Roster.

My goal, for this experiment, is simple: to have nurse "1" be more in favor, and more likely, to work weekends.

I have written the following rules to help make this happen:

```
 rule "nurseNamed1WorksWeekends"
    when
        $oneNurse: Employee( name = "1")
        $wk : ShiftAssignment( isWeekend = true)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end

rule "nurseNamed1MustNotWorkWeekdays"
    when
        $oneNurse: Employee( name = "1")
        not $wk : ShiftAssignment( isWeekend = false)
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);

end
```

However, after running the sample for some time, nurse "1" still never ends up working weekends.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit of rule according to laune's suggestions** but optaplanner is still reluctant to put the nurse on weekend shifts:

```
rule "nurseNamed1WorksWeekends"
when
  $oneNurse: Employee( name == "1", )
  $wk : ShiftAssignment( isWeekend == true, employee == $oneNurse)
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end
rule "nurseNamed1MustNotWorkWeekdays"
when
  $oneNurse: Employee( name == "1")
  not ShiftAssignment( isWeekend = false, employee == $oneNurse)
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `=` in your constraints - test for equality is expressed using `==`.

If the getter for a boolean is called `isWeekend`, the constraint should be written as

```
ShiftAssignment( weekend == true )
ShiftAssignment( weekend == false )
```

or, (for me) preferably

```
ShiftAssignment( weekend )
ShiftAssignment( ! weekend )
```

A binding variable in a Conditional Element such as `$wk` in

```
not $wk : ShiftAssignment( ! isWeekend )
```

doesn't make sense. The rule fires if there is *no such ShiftAssignment* - and then what would `$wk` being bound to?

The CE

```
not ShiftAssignment( ! weekend )
```

is strange: the rule fires *if and only if* there is no ShiftAssignment for any weekday around at all - not likely.

Adding a value higher than one in the "WorksWeekends" rule should favour nurse 1 on weekends.

**Later**

```
rule dislikeNurseOneOnWeekdays
when
  $oneNurse: Employee( name == "1")
  ShiftAssignment( isWeekend = false, employee == $oneNurse)
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

Using a smaller value (e.g. -10) will make it even harder for the First Nurse to work on weekdays: ten shifts during the weekend are needed to balance one during the week.

Comment: Thanks Laune, I can see the error in my drl now - and have corrected it to the following `rule "nurseNamed1WorksWeekends"
 when
  $oneNurse: Employee( name == "1", )
  $wk : ShiftAssignment( isWeekend == true, employee == $oneNurse)
 then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end

rule "nurseNamed1MustNotWorkWeekdays"
 when
  $oneNurse: Employee( name == "1")
  not   ShiftAssignment( isWeekend = false, employee == $oneNurse)
 then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
  
end`. However optaplanner still is reluctant to put this nurse on weekend shifts. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - it's unreadable. Simply add to your Q, as I did to you. Just alert me with a comment.

Comment: I still think that a positive rule reducing the score would be better. Added this to my answer.